# saving data via ajax and JSON with Handsontable to Web API

Tags: ajax, json, post, asp.net-web-api, handsontable

I am sending my Handsontable data via ajax to a Web API POST method, however the data shows up as blank on the web api end. I also used fiddler to see what was being sent and it shows my table data, however for some reason its not being deserialized I am guessing. Heres my code

```
var $container = $("#example");
        var $parent = $container.parent();
        $container.handsontable({
            data: createBigData(),
            colWidths: [150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150], //can also be a number or a function
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            stretchH: 'all',
            contextMenu: true,
            colHeaders: ['Stage Number', 'Horizon Name', 'TVD of top of horizon (feet)', 'Measured depth of top of horizon (feet)',
            'Pool Code', 'Measured depth on well bore-Start (Feet)', 'Measured depth on well bore-End (Feet)', 'True vertical depth on well bore-Start (feet)',
            'True vertical depth on well bore-End (feet)', 'Length of stimulation (feet)', 'Height of stimulation (feet)', 'Direction of stimulation',
            'Volume of Well Stimulation fluid for stage (BBLS)'],

var handsontable = $container.data('handsontable');
        $parent.find('button[name=save]').click(function () {
            var myData = { data: handsontable.getData() }
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/values",
                data: JSON.stringify(myData), //returns all cells' data
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res.result === 'ok') {
                        $console.text('Data saved');
                    }
                    else {
                        $console.text('Save error');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

and heres my Web API method

```
 // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromUri] List<long> data)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        foreach(var value in data)
        {
            //
        }

    }
```

when I debug and step through the code the data contains no data at all!! its blank! Even though fiddler is showing this as my JSON data: (pay no attention to the values, I just typed randomly into the cells)

```
{"data":[["sfgsfs","dfsadfsdf","sdfsdf","fsdf","sdfsdf","sdfsfd"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" ","fsdf"," ","sdfsd"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],["sdf"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," ","fsdf"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," ","sdfsd"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" ","sdf"," "," "," ","sdf"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," ","sdf"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," ","sdf","sdf"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],["sdfsd"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]}
```

Please help! All I want to do is send my Handsontable data to the web api so I can then use that data to insert into my database.

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple mistake in your WebAPI Method.

You have this, which is telling WebAPI to expect the data to be in the URI/URL of the POST:

```
public void Post([FromUri] List<long> data)
```

And it should be this, because the JS is putting the data in the body of the POST:

```
public void Post([FromBody] List<long> data)
```

That is as long as the JSON you are sending it looks like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

If you are actually sending the sample data that you show, then you need to modify your code to understand the object instead of expecting a list of numbers.